user cannot create table on schema public Postgres 16
I have to create a table in Postgres public schema for Airflow implementation. When I create a table with airflow user I get this error
permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE public.PERSONS(

if I run in psql
\dn+ public

I get
                                       List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner       |           Access privileges            |      Description       
--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------
 public | pg_database_owner | pg_database_owner=UC/pg_database_owner+| standard public schema
        |                   | =U/pg_database_owner                  +| 
        |                   | airflow=UC/pg_database_owner           | 
(1 row)

At this stage, I am not understanding what privileges I might be missing for the user after running
CREATE USER airflow PASSWORD
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO airflow
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO airflow


I cannot replicate. To your question add the output of select current_user, session_user; in the session you do the CREATE TABLE.

This is the output of "select current_user, session_user;" ('airflow', 'airflow')

As I said I cannot  replicate, so it must be something with your setup/usage. More information needed: 1) OS and version. 2) Where did you install Postgres from? 3) Do you have more then one instance of Postgres running? 4) Is all the above being done in one session and where the commands committed? Add answers as text update to question text, along with information in your commnet.

Eventually it was due to permission on the airflow database.
In version 14 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE airflow TO airflow was enough, but in Postgres 16 I needed to assign ownership to the airflow user for him to be able to create in the public schema.
There should be a better option than granting ownership though

This is due to the change PG 15 release Notes: Remove PUBLIC creation permission on the public schema. Users/roles start out with the permissions granted the PUBLIC role and that was what allowed your user to create objects in the public schema. Now(15+) you have to specifically add  the CREATE privilege for a role/user. What is confusing is that this airflow=UC/pg_database_owner shows that privilege(C) granted. For more information see Privileges.

CREATE is missing:
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO airflow;


I did run that too but it does not work. You should see from airflow=UC/ from \dn+ public
